# Cannot update photos with Google People API

Tags: google-api, google-people-api

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContact

Here's the wiki on update contact using People API. The update works for fields like 'emailAddresses'. But 'coverPhotos' or 'photos' are not listed as valid value for 'updatePersonFields' and I get return code 400 if I try to update them.

Is changing photos of a contact supported by this API? Or is there any other API that does this job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot update photos, there will be support for updating photos coming in the future. For now you'll need to use the old Contacts API to [update photos](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#addingupdating_a_photo_for_a_contact).

The cover photo is only supported for profiles (it's the big background image in G+), so there isn't any way to set a cover photo on a contact.

Comment: But how do you "translate" Person.resourceName into something you can use in the contactURL to retrieve the contactEntry? I tried attaching People.resourceName to "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/" both with and without the "person/" prefix, no luck.

Comment: a created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/52805040/224239 if anyone could look into it please

Comment: Is it now possible to update the photos data on G+ (or what's left of it) on People API ?

Comment: Since Mid July 2019 it is FINALLY possible to update the contact photo with the people api: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContactPhoto

Answer (score 1):

Since Mid July 2019 it is FINALLY possible to update the contact photo with the people api: https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/updateContactPhoto

Comment: Nope, isn't working for me
```
{
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Resource name \"people/10244712xxxxx1564465\" is not a valid contact person resource.",
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Resource name \"people/10244712xxxxx1564465\" is not a valid contact person resource.",
            "domain": "global",
            "reason": "badRequest"
        }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}


"https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people/10244712xxxxx1564465:updateContactPhoto"
```

Comment: I am using it therefore I can confirm firsthand that it is working. You must have some other error.

Answer (score 0):

people/10244712xxxxx1564465" is not a valid contact person resource. -
maybe you already deleted this contact, and created new?