# Google+ REST API Change Profile Photo

Tags: java, rest, google-api, google-plus, google-workspace

Since yesterday I'm searching for a way to change the "main" Google profile photo with Google REST Apis.

Nowadays, our application can interact and change the User photo with Google Admin API (https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/photos/update) but as described in https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/manage-users#update_photo, in this version of the API, a photo is the user's latest Gmail Chat profile photo, which is different from the Google+ profile photo. If changed, Google+ profile photo override all other photos in Google products.

Is there any obscure way to change Google+ Profile Photo with Google's REST APIs or any other Google product that override all other products profiles photos?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other two APIs to manage photos: People API and Contacts API. As can be seen here ([Cannot update photos with Google People API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45271409/cannot-update-photos-with-google-people-api)) only Contacts API can update a contact's photo.

Today I talked with Google Support and they told that the only way to override all other products is using Contacts API, as it's "local" to the user view.

In my particular case I cannot go this way because there are thousands of accounts to enter (impersonate) just to modify one only contact photo.

So in conclusion there's no such API (or another obscure way) at this moment.