# How do you get from Person to ContactEntry

Tags: google-contacts-api, google-people-api

As far as I know it is not possible (yet) to update photos linked to Person (People API), and it is advised to achieve this using the Contact API.

**But how does one get from Person to ContactEntry?**

I tried to concatenate Person's resourceName to "https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/" but I am getting "ResourceNotFoundException" errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a person with a contact in them, the person will look like:

```
{
  metadata: {
    sources: [
      {
        type: PROFILE,
        id: "12345678"
      },
      {
        type: CONTACT,
        id: "abc123"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

You should find the `metadata.sources` field with type `CONTACT`, then you can use the `id` of that contact in the contacts API. `GET https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/<id>` should return the contact data.